# Многопоточность и boost::interprocess::mapped_region

Tags: c++, многопоточность, boost

Необходимо обработать большой файл (около 100Гб) по блокам, размером 1 Мб следующим образом: 
От каждого блока высчитывается хеш, и записывается в результирующий файл в том же порядке, в каком блок находился в исходном файле.

Хочу ускорить данную процедуру с помощью многопоточной обработки. Также, для ускорения операций ввода-вывода думаю использовать boost::interprocess::mapped_region в комбинации с boost::interprocess::file_mapping. 
Предполагаемый алгоритм работы потока следующий:

1. Получить номер блока для хеширования
2. Отобразить нужный блок файла в адресное пространство процесса
3. Посчитать хеш
4. Записать результат
5. Выгрузить блок из адресного пространства

После прочтения мануалов из boost, и MSDN (по тем функциям, которые вызывает boost) все равно остался вопрос:

Безопасно ли делать отображение параллельно из нескольких потоков, с учетом того, что каждый из них будет создавать свой экземпляр mapped_region? И если да, то можно ли создать одно отображение, размером в весь на все потоки, и в каждом из них брать указатель на нужный блок данных?

Comment: просто вопрос, почему нельзя взять openMP(параллелить for на максимум потоков, сайз файла есть, выделите память под хранение всеъ этиъ хешей)?

Comment: Это лабораторная из университета. OpenMP, OpenCL и прочие библиотеки запрещены условием

Comment: Почему не отобразить весь файл в адресное пространство одним большим регионом? Он все равно будет подтягиваться в оперативку по мере обращения к памяти (в адресном пространстве процесса)?

Comment: Вопрос в том, будет ли безопасным одновременное обращение к этому региону из множества потоков? К примеру отобразил я файл, получил указатель на 0 байт. Поток 1 обратился к байту 1 из файла одновременно с тем, как поток 2 обратился к байту N - 1 (последнему). Гарантируется ли в этом случае, что они оба прочитают то, что ожидалось? И тот же вопрос касается записи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате оказалось обращение оказалось безопасным. Однако маппить сразу весь файл было плохой идеей, так как обращение к данным по смещению, превышающему доступный объем RAM вызывало серьезные замедления в работе. В качестве решения этой проблемы маппил файл блочно, по 1 гигабайту, чем и достиг желаемой производительности.